# how can I get an answer to a part of a question?

Tags: support

There is a question, that is solved by the author itself, but there remains a follow-up question, that cannot be asked on its own without reading the whole question.

how can I restart that question?

[MySQL stored procedure: loop through table, delete rows. Logic problem: won't exit loop because of LIMIT option in query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/mysql-stored-procedure-loop-through-table-delete-rows-logic-problem-wont-ex)

there is a solution but no answer, why that solution is working.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here.  Do you want to ask a RELATED question based on the first question that you linked to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 > https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-i-get-an-answer-to-a-part-of-a-question
```

> [how can I get an answer to a part of a question?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-i-get-an-answer-to-a-part-of-a-question)

If you put a right facing caret and the question link, you can get a nifty title slug like I did above for "free" in the SE Q&A system. You could even put some words before it:

```
 > Related, please read first: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-i-get-an-answer-to-a-part-of-a-question
```

> Related, please read first: [how can I get an answer to a part of a question?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-can-i-get-an-answer-to-a-part-of-a-question)

And this way you can link to the other question in a neat fashion before you ever get into your question, and it's concise and clear.

An alternative is to paste the relevant parts in and decorate around it with "this is from the other question" and etc.

### Another alternative is to just comment on the answer and ask for the author to clarify his position.

I reformulate your "question" below the line as one alternative.

---

> Related, please read this first for context: [MySQL stored procedure: loop through table, delete rows. Logic problem: won't exit loop because of LIMIT option in query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30851/mysql-stored-procedure-loop-through-table-delete-rows-logic-problem-wont-ex)

I don't understand why the solution in that problem works the way it does, can someone explain the solution please?

Comment: thanks, so I hope this is well formatted then: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35199/how-do-uninitialized-variables-differ-from-null-in-mysql